# Printing the sum of rows and columns of 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I am absolutely stuck. Any help would be appreciated. The question asks

> 1.Create two 2-dim arrays/matrices (random numbers, range 1 -500, where 1 and 500 should be declared as class constants). Both have the same dimensions.
>
> 2.Print the arrays.
>
> 3.Call a method to sum the 2 matrices. The sum of 2 matrices matrix_1 and matrix_2 is a matrix result, where for every row r and column c,
>   result_rc= matrix_1_rc+ matrix_2_rc
>
> 4.Print the resulting matrix.

I am stuck on 3 and 4. Part of the problem is I do not get the logic of what 3 is asking. Do I get the sum of each row and each column and add that to the second arrays sum of rows and columns. The second problem is I am absolutely lost on what to do next.

I have been researching for hours and trying different things.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab12p2 {
    public static final int MAX = 500;
    public static final int MIN = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times to run the program");
        int start = scan.nextInt();
        while (start < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error! Should be positive. REENTER");
            start = scan.nextInt();
        }
        // end number of times validation
        while (start > 0)// counter loop for how many times to run program {
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the 2 arrays");
        int SIZE = scan.nextInt();
        while (SIZE < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error! Should be positive. REENTER");
            SIZE = scan.nextInt();
        } // size validation
          // start of methods
        int[][] a = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        int[][] b = new int[SIZE][SIZE];// second array
        System.out.println("The first array is ");
        System.out.println();
        randArray(a, SIZE, SIZE, MIN, MAX);
        System.out.println("The second array is ");
        System.out.println();
        randArray(b, SIZE, SIZE, MIN, MAX);
        sum2arrays(a, b, SIZE, SIZE);
        start--;
    }

    public static void randArray(int[][] matrix, int row, int col, int low, int up) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                int random = matrix[r][c] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
                System.out.print("\t" + random);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void sum2arrays(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int col, int row) {
        int sumrow;
        int sumtotalrow = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix1.length; r++) {
            sumrow = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix1[r].length; c++) {
                sumrow = sumrow + matrix1[r][c];
            }
            sumtotalrow = sumtotalrow + sumrow;
        }
        // testing
        System.out.println("The sum of ALL the elements/row  = " + sumtotalrow);
    }
}
```

It should 
Call a method to sum the 2 matrices. The sum of 2 matrices `matrix_1` and `matrix_2` is a matrix result, where for every `row r` and `column c`,
`result_rc= matrix_1_rc+ matrix_2_rc` (I dont know what that means) and then print the resulting matrix

Comment: Try asking your teacher or instructor if you have any.

Comment: No.  Number 3 means you add each number in matrix 1 to the number in the same position in matrix 2.  So if matrix 1 has 5 in the top left corner, and matrix 2 has 8 in the top left corner, then matrix 1 + matrix 2 will have 13 in the top left corner.  And do the same thing for every element of the matrices.  This, of course, requires that all the matrices have the same number of rows and the same number of columns.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the arrays are random numbers with the same dimensions. Ill work on that. thank you again.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, SIZE).mapToObj(r -> IntStream.range(0, SIZE).map(c -> matrix1[r][c] + matrix2[r][c]).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new)`

Comment: would this go in the main method or inside the sum array method?

Comment: I think I got it

Comment: public static void sum2arrays(int[][] matrix1, int[][]matrix2,int col,int row)
{
    int sumrow;
    ArrayList <Integer> three=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix1.length; r++)
    { 
        sumrow = 0; 
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix1[r].length; c++)
        { 
            three.add( matrix2[r][c] + matrix1[r][c]); 
        }

        
       

    } 
            System.out.println("The matrix result is ");
             System.out.println(three);


}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sum2arrays(int[][] matrix1, int[][]matrix2,int col,int row)
{
int sumrow;
ArrayList <Integer> three=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int r = 0; r < matrix1.length; r++)
{ 
    sumrow = 0; 
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix1[r].length; c++)
    { 
        three.add( matrix2[r][c] + matrix1[r][c]); 
    }




  } 
        System.out.println("The matrix result is ");
         System.out.println(three);


 }
```